# How to print data by current table on page in Laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

My problems are:

1. When I click the print button, it shows the data by text not in table.
2. I want to print data table depends on the current table show. means
   here is on the current page has list of all data and select option.
   When I select or filter table it still print all the data. The data
   here is collected from database.
3. After logged in, why does the image for next page not show?

Here is my JavaScript:

```html
<script lang='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#printPage').click(function(){
            var data = '<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">';
            data += '<div id="div_print">';
            data += $('#report').html();
            data += '</div>';

            myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
            myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
            myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
            myWindow.screenX = 0;
            myWindow.screenY = 0;
            myWindow.document.write(data);
            myWindow.focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Blade template:

```
 <tbody id="result">

        @foreach($profiles as $profile)
        <tr>
            <td class="student_id" width="15%">{{$profile->student_id }}</td>
            <td class="name" width="30%">{{$profile->student_name }}</td>
            <td class="program" width="30%"> {{$profile->program }}</td>
            <td class="faculty" width="25%">{{$profile->faculty }} </td>
        </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p align="center"><button id="printPage">Print</button></p>
```

Comment: what do you want to print the data in? a pdf? or just to any source?

Comment: @GeethW could u help me, how to get parameter for print the data on shown table ? (for example, filter table)

Comment: so you want to get the table in the data as a PDF and print it?

Comment: i already done for pdf file. but, i cannot display data only on the shown table for it page..  
how is my view page? how to call the selected data to be printed? here, on print view page i just call manually from database one by one. i wanna print the only one shown in the screen @GeethW

Comment: so you want to print a specific record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing the method I suggest that you use a PDF generation plugin such as [pdf-laravel](https://github.com/vsmoraes/pdf-laravel5).

PDF-LARAVEL :

- to output to a file

> $router->get('/pdf/output', function() {
>           $html = view('pdfs.example')->render();
>
> ```
>     PDF::load($html)
>         ->filename('/tmp/example1.pdf')
>         ->output();
>
>     return 'PDF saved';
> });
> ```

- Adding the functionality to your controller

  class HomeController extends Controller
  {
      private $pdf;

  ```
  public function __construct(Pdf $pdf)
  {
      $this->pdf = $pdf;
  }

  public function helloWorld()
  {
      $html = view('pdfs.example1')->render();

      return $this->pdf
          ->load($html)
          ->show();
  }
  ```

If you want to search for other options then go to [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) and search for "pdf laravel" and you will find some packages built for Laravel 5 PDF generation.

Comment: by doing this, does it still need javascript? i dont understand on the view side

Comment: nope, it does not require javascript. you jsut have to call the function from your view.

Comment: sorry, i can't get what u just told. how about button print ? can u tell me more details ?

Comment: ohh. i understood right now. it's work already. but how can i get the data from database. how can i change the code below to call table in database and provide model.  :                               public function helloWorld()
    {
        $html = view('print')->render();

        return $this->pdf
            ->load($html)
            ->show();
    } @GeethW

Comment: you want directly print the data from a database or do you want to use the data in the html page and print it?

Comment: In $html = view('pdfs.example')->render(); in this code, the ''pdfs.example' is the folder/name of the view...

Comment: am sorry ! i misunderstood your question. i want the data from database actually.. forgive me

Comment: i tried may times and finally i got it ! it's work.. thank you so much =) now, am focusing on getting the data for the current select option instead of all data. if you don't care, can you help me one more time?

Comment: okey.. thank u =)  how about question number 2? i wanna print by selected data only..

Comment: by using laravel-pdf, how to count row in print view?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question 2:

> I want to print data table depends on the current table show. means
>   here is on the current page has list of all data and select option.
>   When I select or filter table it still print all the data. The data
>   here is collected from database

If you want to filter data and display there, you have two options, either filter data form the controller or you can use **jQuery Datatables** for that. Link [here](https://www.datatables.net/)

All you have to do is:

1. Add the Js.

   https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
2. Add the css

   http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
3. Call your table.

   `$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#myTable').DataTable();
   });`

Comment: how is my view page? how to call the selected data to be printed? here, on print view page i just call manually from database one by one..

Comment: you want to print the entire table or only the ones showned in the screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
function printData()
{
   var print_ = document.getElementById("table_name");
   win = window.open("");
   win.document.write(print_.outerHTML);
   win.print();
   win.close();
}
```

The above function will print the data of a table which are on the current page due to the window.open("") function.